# ACL Implementation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authorization, acl

I am newbie in MongoDB and want to apply ACL on entries of the collection. Can anyone suggest me a good approach to implement this such that it runs as fast as possible since the no of entries may exceed ten million ones. 
Some conditions:

1. every user may have some hundreds of roles but it will not exceed one thousand.
2. The queries applied for different conditions with divers where clauses and they should be authorized for this.
3. For me, just READ authority is important so you can even omit the action param of ACL

Thanks